# Mock-up software that does NOT generate code, but USES code in its own active environment

Tags: windows, software-development, rad

Imagine that you could draw a shape, then add code to that shape that determines how it looks, what it does (visually), or even triggers other events (like play audio files or spawn other shapes), that interact with the user (click, mouse over, drag events, etc), or interact with other shapes.

A good way to imagine it is: What if Adobe Illustrator allowed code to be attached to *any drawn object*, allowing changes in properties **and** behaviors.

And it would be best if it were "live" at all times …

Some mock-up software *sort of* does this, but tends to generate code, rather than USE code.

At this point, I'd create an active demo for you to see how I'd like it to behave, but to do that, I'd actually need the software I'm looking for :)

Comment: Imagine where this would finally end... Where would you stop? Play audio files? Spawn other shapes? Someone else wants to open a browser. Someone certainly only wants to do something `ìf` a condition is met. Someone has a requirement `for` doing things in a loop. The result would be an IDE like Visual Studio instead of a Mockup tool.

Comment: @Thomas Weller - think of it as a magic act.  It looks like it is sawing a woman in half, but in fact does not.  If it does something truly functional, then it went too far.  That's where it stops.  See Flinto for Macintosh.

Comment: Ok, Flinto seems to be a good reference. This makes me wonder: why don't you use Flinto?

Comment: Your last edit seems to clarify: you need it for Windows. Is it safe to say that you're looking for an alternative for Flinto for Windows?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Flinto on steroids, perhaps.  Flinto is just for mobile, and is also interface biased. This is why I mentioned Illustrator... it handles graphics, not interface widgets (though such widgets can always be created by a general graphics engine)  I don't believe that Flinto has code in its widget... but tries to impose expected behaviors based on the widget, a constraint I'd need to avoid.

Comment: @Thomas Weller Adobe Experience Design CC is another that looks pretty good, but again only for Mac.  Apparently, Windows people don't ever need to prototype :)

Comment: Antetype is probably close to perfect.  But *again*, only for Mac.   http://www.antetype.com/

Answer (score 1):

Well, as it turns out... once again, Microsoft Excel stands out as the "universal tool"... useful for just about everything.  While all events are not supported for all shapes, excel vba gives you some ability to control the shapes, and respond to them.  The implementation is cumbersome for the use of an active GUI mock-up  (a responsive mock-up?) tool, it actually does work well enough to get some use out of it.

But unless another package comes along that is tailor made to allow code and events of shapes, focused on movement and appearance... Excel seems to be the winner.

Power Point might also be a contender (as it has VBA), but as it doesn't have macro recording capability, then actually figuring out how it works is going to be stunningly difficult.